# spring sessions limit session to 1 on micro-services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I am trying to limit the session to just 1 on microservices. One is on localhost 8080 and another is on localhost 8181.

`http.httpBasic().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()) .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).permitAll() .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN") .antMatchers("/session-manager/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/**").permitAll() .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") .anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error") .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());`
`http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/home/expired") .and().sessionFixation().newSession();`

For the cookie serializer I set the sameSite variable to none:

`DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer(); cookieSerializer.setSameSite("none");`

I have both these security configs set up the same way for both the projects 8080 and 8181.

What I am trying to do is to have a user that logs in on 8080 be kicked out on 8181 and vice versa. Not having much luck with that